# Tomcat 7 FIFO request Queue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm new in Tomcat 7. I have developed an audio file dispatcher based on Spring MVC and Tomcat 7, nevertheless sometimes I observe that contents aren't served.

I have noticed in the logfiles that Tomcat always tends to accept new requests but the already accepted requests are partially processed but not finished and are interrupted. When sending an audio File as a byte array the above mentioned behavior causes significant problems.

My question is: Is it possible to configure Tomcat 7 in order that requests are processed and finished in a FIFO fashion/manner (I know that Tomcat manages concurrency and that is difficult to obtain a deterministic behavior) ?

Many thanks for your advice and help.

Comment: How can you see request processing is interrupted? can you add the relevant log entries to your question?

Comment: When I observe the timestamps and the IP of the requester I notice that the request is processed until a query to the database is done (MongoDB) and if in the meantime a new request is done, Tomcat interrupts the proccessing of the first request and starts to process the new one. (Thank you for your help)

Comment: Do you see an exception or any other specific log entry which indicates that Tomcat (or something else) interrupted the request processing?